# Difference between identity and diagonal covariance matrices

Tags: probability, statistics, correlation, covariance

thanks in advance for the help.

Suppose I am training a linear model. What are the conceptual differences between using a diagonal covariance matrix and the identity? It is clear to me that the difference between a full covariance matrix and a diagonal covariance matrix is that there is no correlation between predictors with the diagonal matrix. I'm not quite sure of the differences between the identity and diagonal matrices though.

Comment: The identity matrix is a diagonal matrix where all the diagonal entries happen to be equal.  In this case it means the random variables (predictors) all have the same variance.

Comment: yes.  What I don't understand is the effect each would have on training a linear model.  Using the identity matrix is equivalent to using ordinary least squares, when using generalized least squares to find the coefficients.  What does it conceptually mean for each variable to have different variance rather than being equal?  What effect does this have on the coefficients of the model that I create?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by training a linear model. Describe your model, and tell us what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have a set of data [X,Y] where y is the predictor.  I want to build a model that uses X to predict Y.  A covariance matrix defines the variance and covariance of my predictors.  If I use generalized least squares to fit my model, I need the covariance matrix.  Assuming that using either a identity or diagonal covariance matrix are correct approaches (I either assume variance of 1 for each or empirically find the variance of each predictor) what will be the difference in my results?  How will the coefficients of my model be affected?  What is the conceptual difference between their effects?

Comment: Duplicate of [question asked on stats.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/116258/6633) where it has already received two answers.